# switch statement: converting from if-statement to switch statement in swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement, control-flow

I'm trying to convert from below if-statement to switch statement but I'm keep getting error.

```
let meal = "breakfast"

if meal == "breakfast" {
    print("Good morning!")
} else if meal == "lunch" {
    print("Good afternoon!")
} else if meal == "dinner" {
    print("Good evening!")
} else {
    print("Hello!")
}
```

this was my switch statement:

```
switch meal {
let meal = "breakfast"

    case 1: 
        print("Good morning!”)
    case 2: 
        print("Good afternoon!")
    case 3: 
        print("Good evening!")
}
```

Comment: assign `let meal = "breakfast"` before the `switch` and your cases should include the strings:  `case "breakfast"` etc.  And you'll need a `default` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let meal = "breakfast"

   switch meal {

   case "breakfast":

         print("Good morning")

   case "lunch":

          print("Good afternoon!")

   case "dinner":
          print("Good evening!")
   default:

          print("default case")
   }
```

put this switch block in your code :)